An optimal control problem coupled with target allocation
Motivation: What we are doing is to let a group of unmanned surface vessels (USVs) return the fixed berths at the dockside. To make USVs intelligent and us convenient, we want to let them pick their associated berths according to their positions rather than return the pre-assigned berths, which leads to an allocation of USVs and berths.
Notation：$ \mathbf{1}_N $ denotes the $ N $-dimensional all-one vector. $ A=[a_{i,j}] $ denotes the matrix $ A $ with the $ i $-th-row-$ j $-th-column element $ a_{i,j} $. The matrix $ B=[b_{i,j}] $ is a doubly stochastic matrix if $\sum_{i=1}^{N}b_{i,j}=1$ and $ \sum_{j=1}^{N}b_{i,j}=1 $.
Problem Formulation:
Consider a multi-agent system consisting of $ N $ agents and its dynamics can be described as below,
\begin{equation}
  \dot{p}_i=u_i,i\in\mathcal{V}=\left\{1,2,\cdots,N\right\},
 \end{equation}
where $ p_i=\left[x_i,y_i\right]^\top\in\mathbb{R}^2 $ and $ u_i\in\mathbb{R}^2 $ denote the coordinate of the position and the control input of the velocity of agent $ i $ , respectively.
Given a series of fixed target positions $ p_{i,*}=\left[x_{i,*},y_{i,*}\right]^\top\in\mathbb{R}^2 $, define the error
\begin{equation}
  e_{i,j}:=p_i-p_{j,*},i,j\in\mathcal{V}.
 \end{equation}
Define $ \mathbf{u}:=\left[u_1^\top,u_2^\top,\cdots,u_N^\top\right]^\top\in\mathbb{R}^{2N} $ and $ \mathbf{E}:=(B\odot\mathbf{e}^\top)\cdot\mathbf{1}_N\in\mathbb{R}^N $ with the $ N\times N $ matrix $ \mathbf{e}=[e_{i,j}] $ and the doubly stochastic matrix $ B=[b_{i,j}] $, where $ b_{i,j}=0,1 $.
Then, define the performance index as below,
\begin{equation}
  J(\mathbf{u},B)=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{t_f}\mathbf{u}(\tau)^\top Q\mathbf{u}(\tau)+\mathbf{E}(\tau)^\top R\mathbf{E}(\tau)d\tau,
 \end{equation}
with the free final time $ t_f $, where the matrices $ Q $ and $ R $ are symmetric positive. Now, the constrained optimal control problem is motivated as below,
\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
   \min_{\mathbf{u},B}&\quad J(\mathbf{u},B)\\
   s.t.&\quad\left\|p_i-p_j\right\|^2\geq R^2,i,j\in\mathcal{V},i\neq j,\\
   &\quad\dot{p}_i=u_i,i\in\mathcal{V},
  \end{aligned}
 \end{equation}
where the first constraint with the radius $ R>0 $ denotes the collision avoidance.
Our try: we try to divide (4) into two problems: First, solve the $ i $-th-agent-to-$ j $-th-berth optimal control problem with collision avoidance and thus we can obtain a finite final time; Then, according to the obtained time matrix with all the time for $ i,j\in\mathcal{V} $, one needs to solve a mixed integer linear problem and gets the allocation. Unfortunately, we find that we must consider collision avoidance, which leads to the problem (4) cannot be divided. Until now, we have not had any feasible methods to process it.
So, could we find a suitable method to solve this problem?

Do you have a question?  Our site is a question-and-answer site, so we require you to articulate a specific question.  Normally a question ends with a "?".
